# interface component for screwing to make electric contact

Tags: pcb, components

Is there a component that allows you to stack two PCB on top of each other and screw them together to make electric contact? Thanks!

Comment: You mean like PCB interconnects?

Answer (score 5):

You want a non-permanent connection? **Spring Loaded Headers** or **Push Pin headers** need to be pressed together to make a good connection, either with clips, clamps, screws, magnets, etc. (Apple magjacks use push pins held together by magnets, patented unfortunately.)

[image]

The benefit lies in that unlike mated headers like square headers or machine pins,  one board can have simple test points, vias, or otherwise plain unpopulated copper, while the other has the header. Lowers board cost.

Pogo Pins are an extreme version of them.

[image]

If you want a permanent connection, standard headers are cheaper, or even double ended press fit headers.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are screwing the boards together somewhere else, you could use a [Stacker](http://datasheets.avx.com/DualRowStacker_00-9158.pdf).  These only require to be soldered to one of the two circuit boards, with a solder pad/circuit on the other circuit board.

If you are really good with a soldering iron, you could use a [board to board](http://www.avx.com/products/connectors/board-to-board/microleaf-super-microleaf/5078-series/) connector (bigger pitch is easier to solder) for a high circuit count transfer.

Comment: You should disclose your relationship to AVX more clearly (if you ahve one that is)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, sorry, yes, I forgot to mention that I work for AVX.  Thank you for the reminder.