# Raspberry Pi Zero - Male pad or connector for underside contact pads?

Tags: connector, raspberry-pi

I got an idea after reading this hackaday article

http://hackaday.com/2015/11/28/first-raspberry-pi-zero-hack-piggy-back-wifi/

that I could make a daughter board to sit under the Pi Zero and have some form of contact to preclude the need for soldering to the Pi Zero.  I found this EE SE article

[interface component for screwing to make electric contact](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106287/interface-component-for-screwing-to-make-electric-contact)

that has a good part (Spring Loaded Headers), but it seems to be several dollars a piece, so that defeats the point of the Raspberry Pi Zero.

Is there another or different type of connector that I could use in this circumstance?  A sort of male pad for an under daughter board?

Comment: I don't have time to type up a proper answer right now. The 2 word answer is "pogo pins".

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are screwing the boards together somewhere else, you could use a [Stacker](http://datasheets.avx.com/DualRowStacker_00-9158.pdf).  These only require to be soldered to one of the two circuit boards, with a solder pad/circuit on the other circuit board.

Another good solution is to use a [board to board](http://www.avx.com/products/connectors/board-to-board/microleaf-super-microleaf/5078-series/) connector for a high circuit count transfer.  This is a better solution for a manufactured board, as they come in varying stacking heights, pitches and pin counts.

Comment: This would work for a new design, but the poster is trying to match some existing, unevenly placed test pads on an existing product.